# Collection.sort() second sorting based on first ordering

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a list of questions in a `List<RSSQuestion>`, which I am trying to sort: first with their `keyActivity`, then in each `keyActivity` there are `subActivities`; I need to sort out the questions based on the `subActivities`.

For example:

1. OutLine Design (keyActivity)

   1. SubActivity One
2. Specification (keyActivity)

   1. Overview
   2. Backlog

The code that I have is as follows, which is sorting the questions based on the `keyActivity`, but I don't know how can I do the second sorting based on the `subActivity`:

```
private static List<RSSQuestion> sortingExtractedData(List<RSSQuestion> extractedDataByKeyactivity) {
    List<RSSQuestion> exctractedData = new ArrayList<>();

    Collections.sort(extractedDataByKeyactivity, new Comparator<RSSQuestion>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(RSSQuestion o1, RSSQuestion o2) {
            return o1.getKeyActivity().compareTo(o2.getKeyActivity());
        }
    });

    for (RSSQuestion rssQuestion : extractedDataByKeyactivity) {
        Collections.sort(rssQuestion.getSubActivity(), new Comparator<String>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });
    }

    exctractedData.addAll(extractedDataByKeyactivity);
    return exctractedData;
}
```

Please let me know, how can I do the sorting for the rest `subActivities`?

Comment: The question is confusing. How exactly is `subActivity` stored? Is it a list. How do you want to sort `extractedDataByKeyactivity` based on that list? Right now you're sorting the list of `subActivity` itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should all be done with one `Comparator`, but you only go to the `SubActivity` when the `KeyActivity` is the same (i.e. `keyActivityCompare == 0`):

```
Collections.sort(extractedDataByKeyactivity, new Comparator<RSSQuestion>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(RSSQuestion o1, RSSQuestion o2) {
        int keyActivityCompare = o1.getKeyActivity().compareTo(o2.getKeyActivity());
        if (keyActivityCompare == 0)
          return o1.getSubActivity().compareTo(o2.getSubActivity());
        return keyActivityCompare;
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems like `o1.getSubActivity()` is a collection itself. OP is actually sorting it in his code. So this wouldn't work.

Comment: @RohitJain Or, their code didn't work. Otherwise what's wrong with it apart from a confusing name on the getter?

Answer (score 4):

`Collections.sort` is [stable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html):

> the algorithm used by sort does not have to be a mergesort, but it does have to be stable.

That means that if two elements have the same value, the sorting does not change their order. You can make use of this by first sorting on sub activity and then on key activity.

As an example, I sort tuples of numbers, first on the first element, then on the second. Input:

```
(4, 2), (1, 0), (3, 3), (4, 1)
```

First sort on second element:

```
(1, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (3, 3)
```

Then sort again on first element:

```
(1, 0), (3, 3), (4, 1), (4, 2)
```

This way of sorting is reminiscent of [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Radix_sort).